# Elasticsearch aggregation by number of nested elements

Tags: elasticsearch

With Elasticsearch 5.4 I have a document with mapping containing a nested field:

```
top_doc: {
  dynamic: 'strict',
  properties: {
    ...,
    versions: {
      type: 'nested',
      properties: { ... },
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to aggregate over the versions attribute. i.e.

```
"aggregations": {
  "version_count": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": 0,
        "doc_count": 10
      },
      {
        "key": 5,
        "doc_count": 7
      },
      {
        "key": 10,
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've seen various posts mention you need to use a script to do this but I haven't been able to get it working yet as it just returns 0 for all documents:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "versions_count": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "if (doc.containsKey('versions')) { doc['versions'].value.length; } else { return 0; }"
        },
        "interval": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect it's due to the document not containing the versions attribute, perhaps as it's nested?  If I run without the `doc.containsKey('versions')` conditional guard check it errors with:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "No field found for [versions] in mapping with types []"
```

Even though all the other fields are returned successfully.

** Attempt 1 @Peter **

Thanks @Peter though it doesn't work yet:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "versions_nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "versions"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "versions_count": {
          "histogram": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "versions.value.length"
            },
            "interval": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Errors with:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Variable [versions] is not defined."
```

I have iterated through all the documents in a Python script and can confirm they all have a `versions` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how this would work with scripts, but normally for nested document aggs you have to specify the path to the nested document to access it's properties:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "versions_nested": {
      "nested": { "path": "versions" },
      "aggs": { /*Nested properties can be accessed here using path.name, i.e. versions.value*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work yet but thanks @Peter for the suggestion :)

Comment: @AJP Can you make it work with aggregation without using the script? I.e. using for instance a terms aggregation for the field. It might be helpful if you posted the parts of the mapping relevant for this query.